# Jenkins way to generate config files

Tags: jenkins, deployment, configuration, templating

Does Jenkins provide a way to generate per-environment (dev/qa/staging/prod) deployment config files based on some templates using  substitution variables? Kind of like template task in Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Jenkins does not provide this itself. There might be some plugin, which actually does this, but Jenkins in general just executes commands. These commands could then call Ansible, some other templating engine or even `sed` to replace tokens in files.